# How to Move application.properties or Do External Properties in Spring Boot Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

So i was develop some application in Spring Boot, but i get stumbled upon application.properties file, i want to make it easier to use, cause i have some environment to test, like Dev, Uat and Production

When i want to launch the app, i build it using mvn clean install with application.properties profile on the environment. cause my app only using war snapshot for backend service.

like when i want to launch in dev

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

or when i want to deploy it in uat environment i'm using

```
spring.profiles.active=uat
```

is there a way to make it easier, like using external prop, so i don't need using application.properties anymore, cause i'll upload application.properties in each of my environment, so the app can read from external properties.

i already tried PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer, but no luck

```
@Configuration
public class ExternalPropertyConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    Resource[] resources = new Resource[ ] {

    new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/myth_uat_configuration.properties"),
    new FileSystemResource("/myth/app/data/weblogic_configuration/config/myth_dev_configuration.properties"),
    new FileSystemResource("/src/main/resources/myth_local_configuration.properties")
    };

    properties.setLocations( resources );
    properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    properties.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config). So yes you want to specify upon launching which environment you are running in so that you can load the right properties. Now you have several ways of specifying which environment you run in AND Spring Boot has multiple locations it looks in for `application.properties` files (default and profile based). So use it and don't work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building the jar you can launch it like this

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev "app.jar"
```

and providing the active profile will make that particular profile take effect

You just create the profile scoped properties file like `application-dev.properties` or `application-prod.properties`

They are automatically loaded. No need for code to load them

You can have a look at this [Spring Boot Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

Comment: yeah i was asking if there is a way i can do properties without profiles, like ignore location classpath if the properties not found, my PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is to search location my prop, if classpath 1 not found, move to search classpath 2, and if not found , to classpath 3, like that

Comment: Ok. You can define those locations on the command line too.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: thanks for helping, after run it's really work, can we set this argument to Welogic 12c? i'm new to weblogic, so by default i get profile dev in my weblogic

Comment: Which argument? You mean you want to configure spring boot to use Weblogic? One way is to run the weblogic server independently and then just pushing the jar generated from Spring boot to your weblogic server.

Comment: If the above answer helped please accept the answer and upvote thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can load properties using xml configuration as below:

```
<bean id="configProperties"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:nosql.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:api.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

After this you can use property **spring.profiles.active** defined in any of your properties file (any of `db.properties`, `nosql.properties` or `api.properties` ) in your code ->

```
@Service("bean")
public class Bean {
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [Spring boot YML doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml). Generally externalizing the config is achieved through ymls.

Comment: Not related to yaml files. You can use either `.properties` as well as `.yaml`...